# Swift Struct vs Class: what is the allowed stack size? and refactoring a class to a struct

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, refactoring

First, I understand the difference between value and reference types -this isn't that question. I am rewriting some of my code in Swift, and decided to also refactor some of the classes. Therefore, I thought I would see if some of the classes make sense as structs.

**Memory:** I have some model classes that hold very large arrays, that are constantly growing in size (unknown final size), and could exist for hours. First, are there any guidelines about a suggested or absolute size for a struct, since it lives on the stack?

**Refactoring Use:** Since I'm refactoring what right now is a mess with too much dependency, I wonder how I could improve on that. The views and view controllers are mostly easily, it's my model, and what it does, that's always left me wishing for better examples to follow.

`WorkerManager`: Singleton that holds one or two `Worker`s at a time. One will always be recording new data from a sensor, and the other would be reviewing stored data. The view controllers get the `Worker` reference from the `WorkerManager`, and ask the `Worker` for the data to be displayed.

`Worker`: Does everything on a queue, to prevent memory access issues (C array pointers are constantly changing as they grow). **Listening:** The listening `Worker` listens for new data, sends it to a `Processor` object (that it created) that cleans up the data and stores it in C arrays held by the `Worker`. Then, if there is valid data, the `Worker` tells the `Analyzer` (also owned by the worker) to analyze the data and stores it in other C arrays to be fed to views. Both the `Processor` and `Analyzer` need state to know what has happened in the past and what to process and analyze next. The pure raw data is stored in a separate `Record` NSManaged object. **Reviewer** Takes a `Record` and uses the pure raw data to recreate all of the analyzed data so that it can be reviewed. (analyzed data is massive, and I don't want to store it to disk)

Now, my second question is, could/should `Processor` and `Analyzer` be replaced with structs? Or maybe protocols for the `Worker`? They aren't really "objects" in the normal sense, just convenient groups of related methods and the necessary state. And since the code is nearly a thousand lines for each, and I don't want to put it all in one class, or even the same file.

I just don't have a good sense of how to remove all of my state, use pure functions for all of the complex mathematical operations that are performed on the arrays, and where to put them.

Comment: I think the stack/heap part of the question is pretty straightforward. The other part is more of "what is the best practice when you have an object that is large and constantly growing". Since those classes have many working parts, it's too much code to post.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question and comment; your question reads "... size for a struct, since it lives on the stack?", but your comment reads "... the stack/heap part of the question is pretty straightforward". When you say it's straightforward, does that mean you're clear about how to allocate memory for structs from the heap as opposed to just declaring them on the call stack and having the run time handle the memory management for you?

Comment: I'm saying that the question, to me, seems straightforward. I've read that the structs live on the stack, which is where their speed is supposed to come from (this is mentioned in several documents). However, if I have an array in that struct, does that mean that the struct is just holding a pointer to the array (which is on the heap), or is all of it on the stack? This isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 4):

While the struct itself lives on the stack, the array data lives on the heap so that array can grow in size dynamically. So even if you have an array with million items in it and pass it somewhere, none of the items are copied until you change the new array due to the [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) implementation. This is described in details in [2015 WWDC Session 414](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/414/).

As for the second question, I think that [2015 WWDC Session 414](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/414/) again has the answer. The basic check that [Apple engineers recommend](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) for value types are:

> Use a value type when:
>
> - Comparing instance data with == makes sense
> - You want copies to have independent state
> - The data will be used in code across multiple threads
>
> Use a reference type (e.g. use a class) when:
>
> - Comparing instance identity with === makes sense
> - You want to create shared, mutable state

So from what you've described, I think that reference types fit `Processor` and `Analyzer` much better. It doesn't seem that copies of `Processor` and `Analyzer` are valid objects if you've not created new `Producer`s and `Analyzer`s explicitly. Would you not want the changes to these objects to be shared?

Comment: I've watched Session 414, and just checked the transcript, no where does it talk about the stack. And the only references to the heap are when the presenter is talking about objects, not structs.

Comment: And the problem with the value v. reference suggestion, is that this data straddles both domains. The data is used across multiple threads, and must be mutable. However, there is no sense of copies, because only one exists at a time (or two). If I was making hundreds of copies to use across threads it would be horribly inefficient.